# Information about mul in MIPS32 (Computer Architecture)

Tags: mips, mips32

I use mul command to multiple 2 different items of data in register. I wonder if this command will be overflow trap ?

I have 2 registers and I want to multiple data in those 2 registers and save it in another register. But I wonder that will be overflow trap like add command?

Like add 2 positive number by add command we can got a negative number and they call that overflow trap.

Thank you for answering me. I appreciate that